# Syntax for including the value of a declared variable inside a node in PGFPlots annotation?

Tags: julia, pgfplots

In Julia, I have declared a variable, say, x = 3.5. Now I want to include this variable inside some annotation of a plot using PGFPlotsX.

```
x = 3.5

using PGFPlotsX
@pgf Axis(
         plot(
             Table(
             ),
         ),
          raw"node[anchor = south west] at (.3,.3){$x = <variable name i.e., x >$}"
     )
```

What should be the appropriate syntax within the $$ inside the node? I want to avoid hard-coding the value, 3.5, of x inside the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to interpolate inside a `String` when you are  using the `@raw_str` macro which is defined as:

```
help?> @raw_str
  @raw_str -> String

  Create a raw string without interpolation and unescaping. (...)
```

So what you can do is either to not use `raw"` but then you need to escape `$`:

```
"node[anchor = south west] at (.3,.3){\$x = $x >\$}"
```

This will nicely interpolate `x`.

The second option is to concatenate `String`s:

```
 string(raw"node[anchor = south west] at (.3,.3){$x = ", x, raw"  = $x >$}")
```